# Support for XNA in WP8?

Tags: c#, c++, xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

After watching a little bit of the summit keynote I kind of heard conflicting reports about it, but is it official that XNA is being dropped for WP8? I'm guessing since the future version of WP supports previous generation of apps that this is probably not true.

If it is though is using C# even an option for games or is C++ with DirectX the only way to go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the official wp7dev twitter account had this to say too

"XNA Framework apps are fully supported in WP8. The new WP SDK will support building XNA Framework games for both WP7.x & for WP8"
https://twitter.com/wp7dev/status/215513026374270977

Personally given the lack of XNA updates or information and the lack of any Metro support on windows 8 I'm staying a little skeptical until I see an SDK and the publishing rules.

Comment: +1 I have seen that confirmed a couple of times on wp7dev twitter account. As far as the future of XNA as its been in the past, is a matter of waiting now.

Comment: I think all the account is saying, in PR-speak, is that XNA will simply continue as it is now. WP8 is backwards-compatible, so XNA apps will still run on both 7.x and 8.x. I doubt the current state of XNA will change, though. Will be pleasantly surprised if XNA 5.0 is around the corner.

Comment: It's not possible to target WP8 API with XNA apps, you can only run WP7 XNA apps on WP8 devices.

Answer (score 5):

Mary Jo Foley had this to [say about that](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsofts-windows-phone-8-finally-gets-a-real-windows-core/12975):

> Microsoft officials have said the XNA tools/runtime environment used primarily by game developers isn't supported on Windows 8. On Windows Phone 8, XNA is "supported," so existing Windows Phone games will run. But *Microsoft's advice to phone developers going forward, just like it is for Windows 8, is to use native code, meaning C and C++, to write games*.

Comment: Yeah when I read that it kind of threw me off. Should we continue or abandon the idea of using XNA. I understand there are some performance benefits from using C++ but I written a few games that run extremely well using XNA and C# even on the low end devices.

Comment: I'm with @loyalpenguin. There's nothing inherently bad about writing high-performance apps in C# (my entire career has revolved around it) and frankly - that sort of push/suggestion ticks me off. In fact, C# makes it easier to do many things given the amazing language enhancements it's gotten. Not to mention F# which is an awesome functional language.

Comment: I think this guy suffers from a C hacker syndrome or this is a political decision. They want me to write trivia 2D games in C++? Why? What's the benefit? They don't want .Net success cuz it will jeopardize their business? Sure I can switch, but not the language - the platform .

Comment: It does mean that game engines can possibly be more easily ported.

Answer (score 4):

As the public [WP8 SDK is now available](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471), I can confirm that you cannot develop XNA apps for the #WP8 platform directly. You can only target the WP7 platform with your XNA apps and they will run on WP8 devices just fine.

Comment: why would you want to develop a game that only runs on WP8 right now? I've got no problems with this and surely I will not go C++ to write phone-apps :D

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it's too early to speculate on this at this point, we'll see when the SDK is released. But from what I've seen so far - I would say yes, XNA *might* not be officially supported WP8 and onwards (read - new features will probably only be available via the DirectX interface, but existing features will continue to be supported). However, according to [this](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/353549) thread, games that use [Monogame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) to run on Windows 8 metro will pass certification. So in one way or the other, the platform will not die.

**Edit:** I just noticed [this](https://twitter.com/shawnhargreaves/status/215526214868287489) tweet from Shawn Hargreaves: *Windows Phone 8 runs all 7 apps including XNA ones. We're adding new features (native code, D3D) not taking away old ones*

Comment: Interesting tweet. Kind of hoping that implies continued support for XNA. And maybe, just maybe considering it on Win8.

Comment: seems like "life support" more than support. I wonder if i should be removing the dust from my old DirectX books...

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on and off on an XNA game that I had started with VS2010 & WP 7 SDK, and later upgraded to 7.5 (Mango). I loaded up that project in VS2012 and the WP8 SDK and it ran just fine, compiled with no errors and ran smoothly.

As previously stated, XNA projects in VS2012 and the WP8 SDK can only target the WP 7.1 platform. On the upside, all phones running WP 7.5, the upcoming 7.8 and WP8 will run your game without any issues. From that point of view, XNA is fully supported in the WP8 SDK, on WP8 devices, but these WILL NOT be WP8 projects.

By not being WP8 projects, the downside is that you CANNOT use WP8-exclusive features, such as:

- In-app purchasing / micro-transactions (this one hurts XNA devs the
  most)
- Your games will always be 800x480 since you need WP8 projects to support higher resolutions. Your XNA games should automatically scale up when run on devices with a higher res
- Exclusive WP8 networking features & APIs, including Bluetooth and NFC
- Speech and voice recognition APIs
- Your XNA game cannot register a protocol extension for app-to-app communications
- New Live Tile templates

The dev highlights for WP8 are on the wpdev blog at http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/05/windows-phone-8-developer-platform-highlights.aspx.