# WP8 Game dev and C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've got a question about tools and frameworks to use in WP8 games development.

Since now, I've been developing games with C# and XNA and everything was good for me.
But now, after releasing WP8 SDK I don't know what to do, because instead of C# I must use C++.

1. I want to know is there a way to continue creating games for WP8 using C#? Maybe any frameworks? (e.g. monogame) etc. (not to create XNA game projects for 7.x)
2. Also I want to develop crossplatform games, WP8 and Android.
   If it is possible, I will write even in c++.

conclusion:

Is there framework that can:

- crossplatform game develop android and WP8.
- C# is better, but C++ is possible too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for XNA in WP8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127410/support-for-xna-in-wp8)

Comment: no,ive write in post: (not to create XNA game projects for 7.x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) for game development on WP8, Android and if it takes your fancy IOS as well. I believe that XNA will work fine one WP8 but isn't fully supported in the same way WP7 was.

I've taken this from the MSDN page on [XNA for WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> XNA Game Studio 4.0 apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1 remain fully supported and continue to run on Windows Phone 8 devices.
>
> You can continue to develop and maintain new or existing XNA Framework
>   apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.
>
> You can’t upgrade existing XNA Framework apps that target Windows
>   Phone OS 7.1 to target Windows Phone OS 8.0.
>
> You can’t create new XNA Framework apps that target Windows Phone OS
>   8.0.

Comment: Most of that ^ is more about part 2 of your question than part 1. The answer to part 1 is no, you can't use XNA for framework projects on WP8.

Answer (score 1):

Game development is still possible with C# and any CLI compliant language, the only thing you cant do is use the Direct-X Api for faster more fluid games using C#.

And for Android and iOS you have Mono.Net available with tools from Xamarin(just google it).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution ATM is http://www.sharpdx.com/. This is a managed version of the DirectX API and is supported on Windows Phone 8. AFAIK they are also integrating an XNA like API layer into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. For casual games you can get away with XAML and C#. I recommend avoiding binding for better performance. XAML doesn't provide a game loop like XNA, but you can use animations and input triggers to link events together. I have a [couple of games in the store built](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-au/app/swipe-5/7313afef-ecd1-4a56-ad7c-e51bca29256d) on C#/XAML so you can get an idea of what you can do.

If you have specific needs you can write DirectX components in C++, or you can mix-in some SharpDX. I did that for XAudio2 for one of my games and it was pretty straight forward to add that.

For more advanced options Unity provides a dedicated game development platform. In addition to being a great platform Unity also lets you deploy to several platforms.